# How do I get a clickevent on a verbatimTextOutput in an R Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to show a plotoutput instead of my verbatimTextOutput when this very verbatimTextOutput is clicked. How do I change my code to make this happen? I did not manage to find a way to get the clickevent.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
fluidRow(
  verbatimTextOutput("myFirstText")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

   output$myFirstText=renderText({
   "Click on this text to see a histogram of the AirPassengers-data instead of this very text."
   })

   output$myPlot=renderPlot({
   hist(AirPassengers)
   })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is really possible to do what you want. But you could use the `shinyjs` package to get you close. You could try:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
   shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
   fluidRow(
     a(id = "toggleAdvanced", "Click on this text to see a histogram of the AirPassengers-data instead of this very text.", href = "#"),
     shinyjs::hidden(
       div(id = "advanced",
           plotOutput("myPlot")
       )
     )
   )
 )

 server <- function(input, output) {

   shinyjs::onclick("toggleAdvanced",
                    shinyjs::toggle(id = "advanced", anim = TRUE))

   output$myPlot=renderPlot({
     hist(AirPassengers)
   })

 }

 shinyApp(ui, server)
```